# There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name . - [unknown location]

Tags: jsp, tomcat, struts2

i am implementing one small struts 2 web application while i am getting the above exception i am new to struts 2. i have seen some suggestions from stack over flow and other sites. i tried all the suggestions still i could not resolve my problem.

here my strust.xml  and kept in side WEB-INF/ clasess.

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
         <action name="Login">
            <result>pages/login.jsp</result>
        </action> 

        <action name="Welcome" class="com.tcs.action.DemoAction">
            <result name="SUCCESS">pages/welcome.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

</struts>
```

and here is my action class.

```
package com.tcs.action;

public class DemoAction {


    private String userName;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String execute(){

        return  "SUCCESS";
    }

}
```

and i kept login.jsp and welcome.jsp inside webapp/pages folder
and here is my login.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>Struts 2 Hello World Example</h1>

    <s:form action="Welcome">
        <s:textfield name="userName" label="Username" />
        <s:submit />
    </s:form>

</body>
</html>
```

and welcome.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>Struts 2 Hello World Example</h1>

    <h2>
        Hello
        <s:property value="userName" />
    </h2>

</body>
</html>
```

and i hope i added all the struts related jar's since i am not getting any class not found or no class def found exceptions.
i hope i am asking already existing question in so many places still i am not solving the problem.

Comment: Include the same namespace attribute in your <s:form> login.jsp also.

Comment: you mean "/" i did like this but still i am getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

it is funny but i have to say what i did mistake `http://localhost:8089/StrutsApp`
this is my url and i forgot to add `http://localhost:8089/StrutsApp/Login.action` 
that's it. now it is working fine.